# Combinatorics cards question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a 52 cards deck there are 4 sets with 13 cards each. In how many ways
can you choose 5 cards so that every shape (from the 4 sets) is represented on at least one card ?

I'm not sure if its 13^4 * 48 or 13^4 * 48 * 5^5. the addition to the lattar is because each card can be placed in 5 different spots. Or is the answer not even close ? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$$

One set is represented by $2$ cards (the other sets by $1$) and this set can be chosen on $\binom41=4$ ways.

Choosing $2$ cards of this set can be done on $\binom{13}{2}=78$ ways.

Choosing $1$ card of each of the other three sets can be done on $\binom{13}{1}=13$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is close, but it is twice the actual number, because it counts a hand such  as AH, KH, 3S, 2C, 6D twice, once with the AH as the chosen heart and KH from the "48", and once again with the roles  of AH and KH reversed. A simple way to count these hands (1) pick a suit to have 2 cards in (2) pick two cards from that suit (3) pick one card from each of the other suits, and then by multiplication principle you get $4 * (13 * 12)/2 * (13 ^ 3)$ which is exactly half your first answer.